# How to assign value to Struct properties in C

Tags: c, struct, properties

New to C, here is a simple Struct I have created.

```
typedef struct car {
    float x, y;             
    unsigned char width, height;    
} Cars;
```

**My attempt to assign the x and y property of car:**

```
Cars sedan;
sedan.x = 20;
sedan.y = 10;
```

**Error**

> error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '.' token

Any ideas? Please help!

Comment: Did you recompile after making that change?  That was probably the source of your problem.

Comment: Nope still getting same error.

Comment: Then the error is elsewhere, as what you now have doesn't exhibit that error.  Please update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that you have the lines

```
Cars sedan;
sedan.x = 20;
sedan.y = 10;
```

outside a function. You cannot use

```
sedan.x = 20;
sedan.y = 10;
```

outside a function. Move those lines inside a function.

Another choice is to initialize the members of the `struct` using (Thanks @JonathanLeffler)

```
Car sedan = { .x = 20, .y = 10 };
```

Comment: But all this code is defined outside off all functions. There global

Comment: @Shazza, that's the problem. You can use `Car sedan;` outside of all functions but you cannot set its values outside of functions. They have to be set inside a function.

Comment: Or they have to be initialized: `Car sedan = { .x = 20, .y = 10 };`.

Comment: I moved the initialization and assignment inside of the main() and now I am getting these errors:

Comment: : error: request for member 'x' in something not a structure or union
snake.c:283: error: request for member 'y' in something not a structure or union

Comment: @Shazza, I suggest adding a [mcve] to the end of your post. It looks like the definition of the `struct` is not visible at the point where you are trying to set the values of the members.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try defining one member of struct in one line.

```
typedef struct car {
    float x;
    float y;
    unsigned char width;
    unsigned char height;    
} Cars;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct car {
    float x, y;
    unsigned char width, height;
} Cars;

int main( ) {
    Cars sedan;
    sedan.x = 20;
    sedan.y = 10;

    printf( "value one : %f\n", sedan.x);
    printf( "value two : %f\n", sedan.y);
}
```

**Output :**

```
value one : 20.000000
value two : 10.000000
```

You can also code structure as follow, :)

```
struct car {
    float x, y;
    unsigned char width, height;
};

int main( ) {

    struct car sedan;  /* Declare sedan of type car */

    sedan.x = 20;
    sedan.y = 10;

    printf( "value one : %f\n", sedan.x);
    printf( "value two : %f\n", sedan.y);
}
```

Comment: I copied what you have done above moving my initialisation and assignment in the main() and getting this erors: error: request for member 'x' in something not a structure or union
snake.c:283: error: request for member 'y' in something not a structure or union

Comment: what is your compiler, you used to compile your c programs

Comment: I think you confused my answer with previous answers,i'm not used "snake" ??? please reedit or copy my whole code and then try it :)

Good Luck :)